# ARIMA model - non normal time series

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I  am using R, and I have a time series with both positive and negative values.
It is stationary but non-normal.
Acf, pacf and auto. arima suggest a MA(1) model.
I fit this, and the residuals are again non- normal and also  suggest MA(1).

1. Is there some procedure to determine best transformation for the time series?
2. I am bit confused about how to choose the  arima method (maximum likelihood or conditional sum-of-squares).

Many thanks!

Comment: Why are non-normal residuals a problem?

Comment: I think that the assumption for residuals are necessary for an arima model  to be acceptable, isn't that so?

Comment: No. It is not necessary. It is often assumed when producing prediction intervals, but even then it is not necessary as you can bootstrap the residuals when producing prediction intervals.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! How about the time series? Should it be transformed to normal before fitting arima?

Comment: The purpose of transformations with ARIMA models is usually to deal with heteroskedasticity. If the variance increases with the level, a transformation may be required. See otexts.com/fpp2 or otexts.com/fpp3 to learn about ARIMA modelling.